# css - textfield width cannot be expanded

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

This is my current search bar
[image]

I was hoping the input area will be like the Black border I draw.

But actually it starts from center and the input length is restricted.

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-satoshi-x7v65?file=/SearchBar.js

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```js
import React from "react";
import { alpha, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputBase from "@material-ui/core/InputBase";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
   root: {
    padding: '2px 4px',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 400,
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.black, 0.15)
  },
  input: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    flex: 1,
  },
  iconButton: {
    padding: 10,
  }
}));

export default function PrimarySearchAppBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Paper component="form" className={classes.root}>
      <IconButton type="submit" className={classes.iconButton} aria-label="search">
        <SearchIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <InputBase
        className={classes.input}
        placeholder="Search..."
        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Search...' }}
      />
      <IconButton color="primary" className={classes.iconButton} aria-label="directions">
        <CloseIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

Comment: @CCCC Are you facing some error? Please post the same here